# How can I get version information of a package which will be installed using apt on debian-based linux

Tags: linux, vim, debian, apt, package-managers

I have a vim on my debian system. I want to update vim by `apt-get install vim`. But I'm not sure about the version which will be installed. If it is not the version I want, I will install by sources. How can I know what version will be installed? `aptitude search` or `apt-cache search` only gives me a short description, not the version. And `aptitude show` or `apt-get show` gives version information of installed packages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is off-topic for this site. You may check Unix&Linux StackExchange (a sister site, link on the top right icon). To have more control, you may use `aptitude` (and so you can also hold/skip a version), and review, manually adjust dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

`aptitude show` or `apt-cache show` shows available versions in addition to installed versions. Unless you're doing something weird with pins, the highest available version is the one that will be installed.

Since you mention `aptitude`, you can also open up the aptitude TUI and navigate to the package in question. In the overview view, the second-to-last column shows the currently-installed version of the package, and the last column shows the version that will be installed if you use <kbd>+</kbd> to mark the package for installation. If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the package, the detail page will show all available versions, at the bottom.

Comment: `apt show` does show available versions, but I see no information about installed versions.

Answer (score 3):

To get the package version of a package that isn't currently installed on your system, you can use:

#### apt

```
apt-cache policy vim
apt policy vim
```

or

```
apt-cache madison vim
```

or

```
apt list vim
```

#### aptitude

```
aptitude versions vim
```